# Error in eval: object 'input' not found in R Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

My ui.R looks this

```
library(shiny)
library(Sim.DiffProc)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Sliders"),

      sliderInput(inputId = "theta",label="Theta:",
                  min=1, max=50, value=5),

      plotOutput("SDE")
    ))
```

And the server.R is the following

```
library(shiny)
library(Sim.DiffProc)


shinyServer(function(input, output)
{
  result<-reactive({
    f<-expression(x*(1-(x/1000))^input$theta*0.5)
    g<-expression(x*(1-(x/1000))^input$theta*0.2)
    snssde1d(drift=f,diffusion=g, M=5, x0=100)
  })

  output$SDE<-renderPlot({
    plot(result(), plot.type="single", col="lightgrey")})

})
```

I always get the following error: object 'input' not found
I can't figure out what's the problem. Why is not reacting my theta?
Thank you for help!

Comment: drift coefficient: an expression of two variables t and x. (this is f), diffusion coefficient: an expression of two variables t and x (this is g)

Comment: the program work correctly in R. I just can't implement in the right way in Shiny

Comment: Your issue is not the Rshiny. It is the usage of the `expression` function. The expression function is not evaluating `input$theta`. You need to understand what input the expression function accepts. For instance, if you replace `input$theta`, 5. It does produce an output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, As I mentioned the issue of your problem is not Rshiny. It is the usage of the `expression`.

What you are doing here is

```
expression(x*(1-(x/1000))^input$theta*0.2)
```

Which basically outputs the same expression without substituting input$theta, for the value 5.

What you need to do is below

```
 f <- as.expression(bquote(x*(1-(x/1000))^.(input$theta)*0.2))

#bquote evaluates the expression enclosed in .()
```

This outputs

```
expression(x * (1 - (x/1000))^5 * 0.2)
```

I hope it solved your problem